# Combine strategy in Pine script (independent entry and close)

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I want to try a strategy like

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="Breakout", overlay=true, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100, pyramiding = 1, precision=4)
short = input(10)
long = input(20)
start_year = input(2000)
start_month = input(1)
end_year = input(9999)
end_month = input(1)
start     = timestamp(start_year, start_month, 1)  
finish    = timestamp(end_year, end_month, 1)       
window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false

H = max(close,open)
L = min(close,open)
buy1 = crossover(H,highest(H[1],short))
sell1 = crossunder(L,lowest(L[1],short))
buy2 = crossover(H,highest(H[1],long))
sell2 = crossunder(L,lowest(L[1],long))

strategy.entry(id="long1", long=true, when=buy1 and window(), comment="buy1") 
strategy.close("long1", when = sell1 and window(), comment="sell1")
strategy.entry(id="long2", long=true, when=buy2 and window(), comment="buy2") 
strategy.close("long2", when = sell2 and window(), comment="sell2")
```

It's like running two strategies independently, but I want to combine them to see the performance(each entry is 50% of equity). I've tried pyramiding method but it will only trigger buy1 and sell1. Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Did you allow pyramiding in strategy settings? `strategy(..., pyramiding = 2)`

Comment: yes, but it just trigger long1

Comment: Pyramiding will execute any 2 orders, ex: could be 2 orders 'long1' or 'long2', whichever comes first. Backtester is not designed to run 2 independent strategies simultaneously from a single script. a) Use 2 separate scripts, export the strategy report data and compare manually from the csv file, or b) write a custom engine, which could be not so easy, however possible.